# Complex JSX challenge - creating dynamic nested <ul>

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, jsx

The final result required is to have a collapsible, nested <ul> rendered on the page. The list is based on a hierarchical data tree in the following format:

`InitialTree = {data: {id: 0, level: 0, name: 'Your Store'}, parent: null, children: [...and so on]}`

The nodes (<li>s) are to be expandable/collapsible onClick. Beside the node name, they will have three buttons: Add/Edit/Remove that will allow the interactive manipulation of the list.

So far I have achieved the following:

1. Traversing the data tree and collecting the nodes info into an array
   (I call it 'jsx' for later reference). The 'jsx' array is in the order
   of walking through the tree from the top to a leaf, then back to a
   next node below the top, down to a leaf and so on.
2. I can render 'jsx' array, display node name and 3 buttons and can
   interactively manipulate the underlying data tree (adding and
   deleting nodes and editing node names). The tree and the 'jsx' array
   are `useState` variables so the page re-renders after every action. Nice. But this is not a collapsible list. It's just a list of nodes displaying the entire data tree on the page.
3. So, again, based on the 'jsx' array I have created a nested <ul> that renders the top level node and `onClick` toggles visibility of nodes below. Cool, but at the moment nodes only display their names and I need to incorporate the 3 buttons that each has its own `onClick` event.

Below is a screenshot of what I get so far:

[image]

The top of the page shows the collapsible <ul> based on 'jsx' array, which is also dumped under the list. So I can traverse the list by toggling visibility of the nodes and I can click buttons below and manipulate the underlying tree. Now the <ul> on the top must incorporate functionality from the array below. This is where I've got stuck.

The collapsible <ul> is created as follows:

```
export const makeUL = jsx => {
  let prevLevel = null
  let list = `<div style="padding: 30px; text-align: left">`
  list += `<ul id="newlist" className="collapsibleList">`

  jsx.forEach(node => {
    if (node.level < prevLevel) {
      ;[...Array(prevLevel - node.level)].forEach((x, index) => {
        list += `</ul></li>`
      })
    }
    list += `<li>${node.name}${node.hasChildren ? '<ul>' : '</li>'}`

    prevLevel = node.level
  })

  list += `</ul>`
  list += `</div>`

  return list
}

export default makeUL
```

So, that was easy, but the fun begins when trying to add buttons with `onClick` event to the nodes. It just doesn't work (for me). I was passing a `handleOnClick` function along with 'jsx' and various things were happening, the function contents was displaying along the button name or, when I was trying to `bind()` the function I was getting upon clicking "unexpected end of input" or "'e' is undefined" when passing an 'e' (event). Clearly I've got lost here not really knowing what to do.

So, I decided to try and generate the <ul> directly in jsx using `.map()` method hoping that I'll  be able to attach these buttons with `onClick` functions but go stuck there as well. Basically the compiler complains about not closing tags etc, which I kind of understand because looking at the code you can't pair the opening and closing tags, but this is because of looping and conditional statements and in reality all tags would be closed properly.
I insert a screenshot below for you to see where the errors are shown:

[image]

So this is where I am now and at a loss. I see two options at the moment:

1. Incorporate buttons with `onClick`s to the list created by concatenation or
2. Get the JSX fixed so it compiles and works

Can you help with either of the above or suggest another solution?
Please share your ideas. Thank you.

Comment: Why are you trying to conditionally render opening/closing tags? It's JSX so it seems if you know you are starting a new tag, i.e. `ul` or `li` that you go ahead and include both the open and close tag and then render children content into it. You're traversing a tree, so using a recursive component seems like an obvious choice. What you've shared seems like a terribly ineffective way to render JSX.

Comment: A recursive component...? Thanks Drew, I'll do some reading...

Comment: Thanks again Drew! I didn't know about recursive components. Now I know and have implemented my tree using one (or more them being recursive ;-). Awesomely simple...

Comment: Welcome, sounds like you resolved your question, might be worth posting an answer. Cheers and good luck.